# PCA scatterplot in python

Tags: python, data-analysis, pca

I have a matric/csv file with responses form a online survey.

Like this

[CSV file of responses, Likert scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTZ4E.png)

I want to use PCA and plot this in a scatterplot or biplot to see the groupings of each sample/person.

My challange is: "how do I actually read a scatterplot made form this?" Using my code it only plots without names or colourcoding. Is it any way to add the ID so that I can look at my scatterplot and be able to go back to the csv file at idenofy clusters based on the IDs?

**Scoreplot code**

def scoreplot(self, pc0, pc1):

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))


    plt.scatter(
    self.scores[:,pc0], self.scores[:,pc1], edgecolor="none", alpha=0.8, c="blue"
)
    plt.title('Scoreplot')
    plt.xlabel('Principal Component: ' + str(pc0))
    plt.ylabel('Principal Component: ' + str(pc1))
    plt.show()
```

I did try the code, but I want to be able to look at the scatterplot at map the responses back to original CSV file to identify clusters